Which space is less regular in the sense of PDE theory : $L^1(\Omega)$ or $H^{-1}(\Omega)$?
I was studying the book of Tomas Roubicek called Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations with Applications, specifically the Chapter 3, about some basic topics of Accretive Theory. In one of the sections, he talk about the well-posedness of some heat related problems in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$, and before that, shows that 2nd order problems can be solved using a data $g \in L^{1}(\Omega)$. With this in mind, my questions are :

What kind of data it is less regular, $L^1(\Omega)$ or $H^{-1}(\Omega)$? I mean, this concept of regular it's related to "How much general is the data". For example, one could hastily say $L^2(\Omega) \subset H^{-1}(\Omega)$, and this implies that the data in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ it is less regular instead a data in $L^2(\Omega)$.
Are there any notes that could have this detailed information, how regular are the data types in PDE?

Thanks!

This is hard to answer: if $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ with $d>1$ then $L^1(\Omega) \not \subset H^{-1}(\Omega)$ and $H^{-1}(\Omega) \not\subset L^1(\Omega)$. So none of the spaces is larger/smaller than the other.
One might argue that $L^1$ is more regular, as it contains integrable functions.
There is also an argument for $H^{-1}$ being more regular: Solutions to the equation $-\Delta u=f$ and $f\in H^{-1}$ plus homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions belong to $H^1(\Omega)$. If $f$ is in $L^1(\Omega)$ this is not the case for $d\ge 2$ and it is harder to prove existence of solutions.

The situation is clearer when one considers $L^2(\Omega)$, as naturally $L^2(\Omega)$ is embedded into $H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Also in the $d=1$ case, $L^1(\Omega)$ is embedded into $H^{-1}(\Omega)$.
